# Animate / Flash CC, AS3. Want to toggle button.upState on and off

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, jquery-animate, simplebutton

I'm working on a school project right now. I've searched far and wide and haven't found a solution.

I have 2 `simpleButtons`. One is named `btOui`, the other `btNon`. I was looking for a way to make `btOui`'s downState be `false` when `btNon`'s downState is `true`, and vice versa. I was using :

```
btNon.upState = btNon.downState;
```

// And

```
btNon.upState = btNon.upState;
```

But my understanding is that `btNon`'s `upState` gets overridden by its `downState`. In a way, `btNon`'s `upState` is now a copy of its `downState`, so I can never get its original `upState` again.

I hope I'm being clear. I'm not particularly in a hurry, but any answer is appreciated !

Comment: use a temporary variable to store the state before it's overridden

Comment: it would be helpful to you if you provide the code you are having problem in.

Comment: You should not need a Boolean for up and another one for down.  That is the whole point of a Boolean value... Just one value that tells if something is true or not.  Just have a value called `_isUp` and if that value is true, then the button is up, if the it is false, then the button is down.

Comment: Are you trying to create some buttons behaving as radio buttons?

Comment: I tried using a variable to store the state. In example, storedUpState = btOui.upState. However, since btOui,upState gets overridden, storedUpState just ends up = to the new state that is stored in btOui.upState.

Comment: Yes, in a way, I am trying to make them behave like radio buttons

Comment: You may use http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/controls/RadioButton.html. If you further want to change the looks of radio buttons then have a look at http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_UsingComponentsAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9c65b32-7f1b.html

Answer (score 0):

Try the following program

```
if(btNon.upState)
{
    btNon.downState = false;
}
else
{
    btNon.downState = true;
}
```

Comment: btNon.downState should be a DisplayObject, not a Boolean. I had the same reflexion as you but Flash didn't like it. Thank you though !